# There is a crash at CcInitializeCacheMap

Tags: c++, windows, windows-process

```
/*
typedef struct _HRFS_VOLUME_CONTROL_BLOCK
{
    
    FSRTL_ADVANCED_FCB_HEADER VolumeFileHeader;
    ULONG nodeType;
    FAST_MUTEX AdvancedFcbHeaderMutex;
    ....
};
*/
DumpFileObject(*(pVolDev->fileObject));
Vcb = (HRFS_VOLUME_CONTROL_BLOCK_PTR)ExAllocatePool(PagedPool, sizeof(HRFS_VOLUME_CONTROL_BLOCK));

pVolDev->fileObject->SectionObjectPointer = \
    (PSECTION_OBJECT_POINTERS)ExAllocatePool(PagedPool, sizeof(SECTION_OBJECT_POINTERS));;
pVolDev->fileObject->WriteAccess = TRUE;
pVolDev->fileObject->ReadAccess = TRUE;
pVolDev->fileObject->DeleteAccess = TRUE;
pVolDev->fileObject->FsContext = &HrfsData.gVolume;
pVolDev->fileObject->Vpb = Vpb;

CC_FILE_SIZES fileSize;
fileSize.AllocationSize.QuadPart =    fileSize.FileSize.QuadPart = sizeof(PACKED_BOOT_SECTOR);
fileSize.ValidDataLength.QuadPart = 0xFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF;
            
CcInitializeCacheMap(pVolDev->fileObject,
                &fileSize,
                TRUE,
                &HrfsData.CacheManagerNoOpCallbacks,
                Vcb);
```

In this Code segment a crash  occured when I call the CcInitializeCacheMap function.

The FILE_OBJECT and the dump infomation is as below :

```
fileObject.Size : d8
fileObject.DeviceObject : c2221670
fileObject.Vpb : c39302e0
 fileObject.FsContext : 32166f0
fileObject.FsContext2 : 0
fileObject.SectionObjectPointer : 0
fileObject.PrivateCacheMap : 0
fileObject.FinalStatus : 0
fileObject.RelatedFileObject : 0
 fileObject.LockOperation : 0
fileObject.DeletePending : 0
 fileObject.ReadAccess : 1
fileObject.WriteAccess : 1
fileObject.DeleteAccess : 1
fileObject.SharedRead : 0
fileObject.SharedWrite : 0
fileObject.SharedDelete : 0
fileObject.Flags : 40100
fileObject.FileName : 247bb70
fileObject.CurrentByteOffset : 0
fileObject.Waiters : 0
fileObject.Busy : 0
fileObject.LastLock : 0
fileObject.FileObjectExtension : 0
```

The stack text is as below:

```
fffff880`0247bac0 fffff880`03241c78 : fffff880`00000000 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000001 fffff880`032166c8 : nt!CcInitializeCacheMap+0xd3
fffff880`0247bba0 fffff880`0323e095 : fffffa80`c303b010 fffffa80`c2222040 fffffa80`c39302e0 fffffa80`c3d56a40 : fastfatDemo!FatMountVolume+0xaf8 [G:\BaiduNetdiskDownload\fastfat_V1G13\fastfat_File_System_Driver\FsCtrl.c @ 1460] 
fffff880`0247c2f0 fffff880`0323ecb7 : fffffa80`c303b010 fffffa80`c259bb40 00000000`00000065 00000000`00000003 : fastfatDemo!FatCommonFileSystemControl+0xe5 [G:\BaiduNetdiskDownload\fastfat_V1G13\fastfat_File_System_Driver\FsCtrl.c @ 1053] 
fffff880`0247c340 fffff880`0113d4bc : fffffa80`c3d56a40 fffffa80`c259bb40 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 : fastfatDemo!FatFsdFileSystemControl+0x127 [G:\BaiduNetdiskDownload\fastfat_V1G13\fastfat_File_System_Driver\FsCtrl.c @ 969] 
fffff880`0247c3a0 fffff880`01138971 : fffffa80`c3d56450 00000000`00000000 fffffa80`c3024200 fffffa80`c3129cb0 : fltmgr!FltpFsControlMountVolume+0x28c
fffff880`0247c470 fffff800`04334e6b : fffffa80`c3d56450 00000000`00000000 fffffa80`c3d56450 fffffa80`c259bb40 : fltmgr!FltpFsControl+0x101
fffff880`0247c4d0 fffff800`040789e7 : fffff880`0247c7c0 fffff880`0247c701 fffffa80`c2221600 00000000`00000000 : nt!IopMountVolume+0x28f
fffff880`0247c590 fffff800`044fac6d : 00000000`00000025 00000000`00000000 fffff880`0247c7c0 fffff880`0247c768 : nt!IopCheckVpbMounted+0x1b7
fffff880`0247c600 fffff800`044229a4 : fffffa80`c2221670 00000000`00000000 fffffa80`c31dbb10 fffff8a0`00000001 : nt!IopParseDevice+0xb4d
fffff880`0247c760 fffff800`042fd756 : 00000000`00000000 fffff880`0247c8e0 00000000`00000040 fffffa80`c15c07b0 : nt!ObpLookupObjectName+0x784
fffff880`0247c860 fffff800`044c9d88 : fffffa80`c3d20cb0 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000401 fffff800`043fdef6 : nt!ObOpenObjectByName+0x306
fffff880`0247c930 fffff800`0435d7f4 : fffffa80`c629f870 fffff8a0`80100080 00000000`0029f4f8 00000000`0029f448 : nt!IopCreateFile+0xa08
fffff880`0247c9e0 fffff800`040b4bd3 : fffffa80`c3539b00 00000000`00000001 fffffa80`c629f870 fffff800`042fe1e4 : nt!NtCreateFile+0x78
fffff880`0247ca70 00000000`77629dda : 000007fe`fd3760d6 00000000`00000000 00000000`80000000 00000000`00000000 : nt!KiSystemServiceCopyEnd+0x13
00000000`0029f428 000007fe`fd3760d6 : 00000000`00000000 00000000`80000000 00000000`00000000 00000000`000c0000 : ntdll!ZwCreateFile+0xa
00000000`0029f430 00000000`773b0add : 00000000`0034bec0 00000000`80000000 00000000`00000003 00000000`0029f892 : KERNELBASE!CreateFileW+0x2cd
00000000`0029f590 000007fe`f1971c1e : 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 00000000`01d14280 00000000`0029f830 : kernel32!CreateFileWImplementation+0x7d
00000000`0029f5f0 00000000`00000000 : 00000000`00000000 00000000`01d14280 00000000`0029f830 00000000`00000003 : FVEAPI+0x1c1e
```

I traced the address to nt!CcInitializeCacheMap+0xd3
and found there is a compaire instruction .

So what courced the crash to CcInitializeCacheMap by my program ?

Comment: `fileObject.SectionObjectPointer : 0` and from src code of *CcInitializeCacheMap* - `if (FileObject->SectionObjectPointer->SharedCacheMap == NULL)` so you crash exactly in this place. `FileObject->SectionObjectPointer` must be not 0

Comment: you must by self allocate `SECTION_OBJECT_POINTERS` storage and assign it to `FileObject->SectionObjectPointer` before call `CcInitializeCacheMap`. you need also `FSRTL_COMMON_FCB_HEADER` have on file.. not so simple use *Cc*

Comment: Thank you very much! This suggetsion is very helpful .

Comment: Thank you very much! This suggetsion is very helpful . I had modified the code and adding the allocation to the FileObject->SectionObjectPointer . Do I need to set FileObject->SectionObjectPointer->SharedCacheMap value before CcInitializeCacheMap  ?   And FSRTL_COMMON_FCB_HEADER  may not a FILE_OBJECT member . Do you mean that may set in other codes ? @RbMm

Answer (score 0):

This code should not set to PagedPool Type .

```
//ErrorCode:
Vcb = (HRFS_VOLUME_CONTROL_BLOCK_PTR)ExAllocatePool(PagedPool, sizeof(HRFS_VOLUME_CONTROL_BLOCK));
pVolDev->fileObject->SectionObjectPointer = \
    (PSECTION_OBJECT_POINTERS)ExAllocatePool(PagedPool, sizeof(SECTION_OBJECT_POINTERS));;
```